# Static field/property initialization

Tags: c#, .net, performance, initialization

If I have a type like this:

```
public struct Effect
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public static int MinValue = Int32.MinValue;
}
```

Would `MinValue` be initialized only ONCE, just like the execution of a static constructor? Or should I initialize `MinValue` inside a static constructor?

Would this be any different for `classes`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be executed exactly once, but not *quite* as if it were in a static constructor. The rules about when type initializers are executed are [different when a type has a static constructor](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/BeforeFieldInit.aspx). Note that the observed behaviour [changed a bit in .NET 4.0](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/01/26/type-initialization-changes-in-net-4-0.aspx), too. Usually you don't need to worry about that though.

As far as I'm aware, there's no difference in type initialization between classes and structs.

Note that your `MinValue` field is public and *writable* - is it meant to be? That seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks Jon, haven't seen your posts myself for a long time. I actually compile against .NET 4.0. You are right, it wasn't intentional to have the MinValue as writable.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it would initialize exactly once, before static constructor execution. Same for reference types (classes).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it will be initialized only once per process (app domain).